# Animation doesnt work when onClick event occurs (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, classname, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm creating a simple hamburger menu and I want to add new className to  element when onClick event occurs. This new className should transform the  element, but when onClick occurs element  dissapears, animation doesn't work. I understand the problem is in **classes.line[i]** part, but what could be the problem maybe someone can help me here.

link to the example https://repl.it/@RokasSimkus/DelectableFrugalMuse

**jsx:**

```
   const menu = (props) =>{
  let lineArray= ['', '', ''];
  let lines= lineArray.map((lineArray, i) => {
  return <span key={"classes.line" + i} className={!props.active ? classes.line : classes.line[i]}></span>
});
console.log(props.active);
  return(
  <>
<div className={!props.active ? classes.hamburger: classes.hamburger}
onClick={props.open}
onMouseOver={props.mouseHover}
onMouseLeave={props.leaveMouseHover}>
{lines}
</div>
</>
)
};
```

**css code:**

```
 @media(min-width: 500px){
  .hamburger{
        display: none;
  }
}
.hamburger {
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
.hamburger .line {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 8px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  .line:nth-of-type(1) {
    transform: translateX(15px);
    width: 40px;
  }
}

.hamburger .line1 {
  transform: translate(4px, 1px) rotate(45deg);
  width: 18px;
}

.hamburger .line2 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 51px;
}

.hamburger .line3 {
  transform: translate(14px, 4px) rotate(45deg);
  width: 28px;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

Comment: Can you include a link to a live example?

Comment: Hi, I added the example here: https://repl.it/@RokasSimkus/DelectableFrugalMuse

Comment: I recommend you to check https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition You may need to have the animation changes also timed in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change the line you marked to the following, it works:

```
return <span key={"classes.line" + i} className={`${classes.line} ${props.active ? `${classes["line" + i]}` : ''}`}></span>
```

To show anything, your lines need the class `.line`. To be in the "active" state, they need to add their respective `.lineX` class to add the transform you want to see. As you need both classes at the same time, you need to put both into the className property, which I've done here by putting them together into a string.

I'd suggest to change your CSS and add an `active` class to your menu.

The underlying problem is that you need to add multiple classes to your elements at some point. You can do that with string interpolation like I showed above (same would be for adding an `active` class to `.menu`) or you could use a module like [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) which does a great job concatenating classes. Thus you could write

```
return <span key={"classes.line" + i} className={classnames(classes.line, props.active && classes["line" + i])}></span>
```

I'd still suggest to create an `active` modifier class on your "root" element of your component, to keep modifiers on the top level and your code a bit more understandable. Here is [your modified example](https://repl.it/repls/InsidiousShyManagement).